# Google app script extracting data and registering emails in a table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my very first kinda interaction here.
I have written a script in google spreadsheet to extract data from a table and send it automatically by email.

Its all working great for now , but i am having these 2 problems that I hope that someone might help me solve it:

**1st problem:**

The extracted data isn't including the last row of the table, if the table has 50 rows, its only extracting 49 rows.

**2nd Question is:**
I have a table that has the customer name and customer email address.
Lets say the same customer has 2 emails, should I create 2 rows for the same customer or i can add both emails in 1 cell ?

**Example:**

Customer 1   import@customer1.com
Customer 1   Marketing@customer1.com

**or**

Customer 1   import@customer1.com ; marketing@customer1.com (in one cell)

Thank you in advance

Here is the code:

```
function myFunction() {
  vs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var i;
  var j;
  var k;
  var l;
  var name;
  var dsCustName;
  var custSheetLastRow;
  var emailAddress;
  var emailSubject;
  var emailMessage;
  var emailName;

  ds = vs.getSheets()[0];
  var mainSheetLastRow = ds.getLastRow();
  var shtName = ds.getName();
  Logger.log(shtName);

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-5:30", "dd/MM/yyyy");
  var custNameDate = new Date();

  ts = vs.getSheetByName('Email');

  cs = vs.insertSheet('Customer Name' + date);

  cs.getRange('A1').setValue('Customer Names');
  cs.setColumnWidth(1, 250);

  cs.getRange('A2').setFormula('=UNIQUE(Sheet1!G2:G' + mainSheetLastRow + ')');

  var custNameLastRow = cs.getLastRow();

  for (i = 2; i <= custNameLastRow; i++) {

    name = cs.getRange('A' + i).getValue();

    vvs = SpreadsheetApp.create(name + custNameDate);
    dds = vvs.getActiveSheet();

    var dataToCopy = ds.getRange('A1:J' + mainSheetLastRow);
    var lastRow = dds.getLastRow();

    for (k = 1; k <= 9; k++) {
      var Paste = dds.getRange(lastRow + 1, k).setValues(dataToCopy.getCell(1, k).getValues());
    }

    for (var j = 1; j <= mainSheetLastRow; j++) {
      var dataToCopy = ds.getRange('A1:J' + mainSheetLastRow);
      var lastRow = dds.getLastRow();
      dsCustName = ds.getRange('G' + j).getValue();

      if (name == dsCustName) {
        for (k = 1; k <= 9; k++) {
          var Paste = dds.getRange(lastRow + 1, k).setValues(dataToCopy.getCell(j, k).getValues());
        }
      }

    }

    var emailLastRow = ts.getLastRow();

    for (l = 2; l <= emailLastRow; l++) {
      emailName = ts.getRange('A' + l).getValue();
      emailAddress = ts.getRange('B' + l).getValue();
      emailSubject = ts.getRange('C' + l).getValue();
      emailMessage = ts.getRange('D' + l).getValue();

      if (name == emailName) {
        try {
          var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + vvs.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";

          var params = {
            method: "get",
            headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() },
            muteHttpExceptions: true
          };

          var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();

          blob.setName(dds.getName() + ".xlsx");

          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, emailSubject, emailMessage, { attachments: [blob] });

        } catch (f) {
          Logger.log(f.toString());
        }
      }
    }

    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name + custNameDate);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      file.setTrashed(true);
    }

  }

  cs.activate();
  vs.deleteActiveSheet();

}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: As for 2nd question, "1 row = 1 email" variant is obviously easier to implement.

Comment: Thanks for your response,
am having a hard time pasting the code in the original post

for the second part as well, okay i will follow this 1 row 1 email

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zNF3fNlSIlFpqEgzB6I6f_6SdC1U_Z2aG7wlwOdL2y8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: See [ask]. Ask only 1 question per post.

Comment: Sorry, but this is exactly the kind of code that nobody wants to untangle. As you can see. Too much global variables with cryptic names, no comments, no short clear functions, triply nested loops, no real sample of date (the code is not reproducible), too much `getValue()`/`setValue()`, etc. Perhaps, it's impossible to tell with no real data, one of your variables (`k`?) was wrong reused within of one of your loops. I don't know. I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that there is a one-off error in your `for` loop. To include all rows, use a `forEach()` loop, like this:

```
function moot() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  values.forEach(row => {
    const name = row[0];
    const emailAddress = row[10];
    // ...
  }
}
```

To specify multiple email addresses, but the addresses in the same cell separated with commas.

Comment: This is my code, for some reasons its not being posted in the post directly 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zNF3fNlSIlFpqEgzB6I6f_6SdC1U_Z2aG7wlwOdL2y8/edit?usp=sharing